# How do I change the order of tile evaluation in Apache Tiles?

Tags: java, jsp, tiles, apache-tiles

I have a problem where the nested templates are being evaluated before the parent template.  Due to the ordering issue, this is causing issues with a tag library that insists nesting.

template.jsp

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://taglibs.com/tags" prefix="s"%>
<%System.out.println("evaluating template.jsp");%>
<s:outer>
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="content" />
</s:outer>
```

content.jsp

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://taglibs.com/tags" prefix="s"%>
<tiles:insertDefinition name="template">
    <tiles:putAttribute name="content" />
        <%System.out.println("evaluating content.jsp");%>
        <s:inner />
    </tiles:putAttribute>
</tiles:insertDefinition>
```

When the `content.jsp` page is evaluated, the following is output.

```
evaluating content.jsp
evaluating template.jsp
```

The `content.jsp` page is failing because the `inner` tag must be inside the `outer` tag.  How do I get Tiles to evaluate `content.jsp` after it has evaluated `template.jsp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong but I think Tiles needs to parse the whole JSP, which means you can't do it just the way it is laid out.  The current layout goes from a target JSP which then uses a template internally. We can use tiles definitions to specify the template as the target filling in the content.  I think this method will let you use tiles inheritance more efficiently and may solve this issue because the "template" will be rendered first and not second.

Example:
tiles.xml

```
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="myTemplate" template="/WEB-INF/jsf/template.jsp">
         <put-attribute name="content" value="" />
    </definition>
    <definition name="content" extends="myTemplate">
         <put-attribute name="content" value="content.jsp" />
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

Now you must specify a tiles defintion as your result type... If you're using struts2 I'd tell you but chances are with all the frameworks your not.

Your template jsp would stay looking the same.
and your content jsp would be rewritten something like:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://taglibs.com/tags" prefix="s"%>
<%System.out.println("evaluating content.jsp");%>
<s:inner />
```

Note there is now no need to mix any tiles logic into the page.  The content is just that.  You'll notice that the tiles.xml file is more complicated than I really needed but I wanted to show that in our example we only have one 'put attribute' but in more complicated pages you can have many and so 'myTemplate' would produce a page with includes not only for content but header and footer and side bars perhaps even headers so you can change the scripts and CSS on the page and then you simply extend it as in the example given and then change only the pieces you want (typically it is only the content), further you can extend that definition... Base Layout -> Secure Layout extends Base but perhaps changes the header to include a lock icon -> View_users_in_secure_layout extends secure layout changing the content for the view users function.

Comment: The problem that I'm having with Tiles is that I want all of the page content to be within one JSP page - html head content, page-specific css, menu, and content.  It appears that Tiles isn't going to work as I want.  Thanks for you input!